# View different in IReport and Netbeans

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My report view doesnt any problem with blanks and it seems in one page. But when I run Netbeans it split two pages. Does anyway for clear blanks?

Note:

*I did:"Remove Line When Blank" but it doesnt solve my problem

[image: My İreport View]

My Print Code:

```
try {
            Connection baglanti = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/KontrolCetveli", "postgres", "12qw!'QW");
            String rapor = "C:\Users\00035583\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Kontrol Paneli\src\ayOlusturma.jrxml";
            String temizle = "truncate sorgutablosu";
            st = baglanti.createStatement();
            st.execute(temizle);
            String sql = "insert into sorgutablosu(sicilno,ad,gorev,servisadi,ay) VALUES ('" + txtSicilNo.getText() + "','" + txtAdSoyad.getText() + "',"
                    + "'" + txtGorev.getText() + "','" + ComboServis.getSelectedItem() + "','" + Combom.getSelectedItem() + "') ";
            st = baglanti.createStatement();
            st.execute(sql);
            JasperReport JR = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(rapor);
            JasperPrint JP = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JR, null, baglanti);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(JP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Are you really pass the "insert into" query to report? You should also post the *jrxml* and image for illustrating your problem

Comment: It save in database after then query from database.Thanks for your interest. I solved it with selection "float column footer" in report name.

Comment: You can post the solution as the asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with selection "float column footer" in report name.